# json ajax problem

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I am sorry to ask this but i've been working on this for hours and I can't figure it out on my own.

I have to use json for part of a project and I was able to get it to work but now it's not returning it back to the right jsp but instead just displaying the json jsp. I am pretty sure it is how I am receiving the json.

here are screen shots of what is happening:

this is the jsp that I need to use ajax on, I am wanting to populate the second dropdown using ajax:

[image: the jsp I want to use ajax on]

this is what is happening instead, (it's the right data):

[image]

here is the code(sorry it's long):

-the jsp I am doing ajax on

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

/**
 * Utility function to create the Ajax request object in a cross-browser way.
 * The cool thing about this function is you can send the parameters in a two-dimensional
 * array.  It also lets you send the name of the function to call when the response
 * comes back.
 *
 * This is a generalized function you can copy directly into your code. *
 */
function doAjax(responseFunc, url, parameters) {
  // create the AJAX object
  var xmlHttp = undefined;
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (othermicrosoft){
      try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {}
    }
  }
  if (xmlHttp == undefined && window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // If IE7+, Mozilla, Safari, etc: Use native object
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (xmlHttp != undefined) {
    // open the connections
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    // callback handler
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // test if the response is finished coming down
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        // create a JS object out of the response text
            var obj = eval("(" + xmlHttp.responseText + ")");
        // call the response function
        responseFunc(obj);
      }
    }

    // create the parameter string
    // iterate the parameters array
    var parameterString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
      parameterString += (i > 0 ? "&" : "") + parameters[i][0] + "=" + encodeURI(parameters[i][1]);
    }

    // set the necessary request headers
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameterString.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    // send the parameters
    xmlHttp.send(parameterString);
  }
}//doAjax

/**
 * Submits the guess to the server.  This is the event code, very much
 * like an actionPerformed in Java.
 */
function getSeats() {
  // this is how you get a reference to any part of the page
  var packInput = document.getElementById("pack");
  var pack = packInput.value;
//  while (packInput.childNodes.length > 0) { // clear it out
//    aSeats.removeChild(aSeats.childNodes[0]);
//  }

  // an example of how to do an alert (use these for debugging)
  // I've just got this here so that we know the event was triggered
  //alert("You guessed " + seat);

  // send to the server (this is relative to our current page)
  // THIS IS THE EXAMPLE OF HOW TO CALL AJAX
  doAjax(receiveAnswer, "ttp.actions.Sale3PackAction.action",
    [["pack", pack]]);

  // change the history div color, just 'cause we can
//  var randhex = (Math.round(0xFFFFFF * Math.random()).toString(16) + "000000").replace(/([a-f0-9]{6}).+/, "#$1").toUpperCase();
//  document.getElementById("history").style.background = randhex;
}

/**
 * Receives the response from the server.  Our doAjax() function above
 * turns the response text into a Javascript object, which it sends as the
 * single parameter to this method.
 */
    function receiveAnswer(response) {
  // show the response pack.  For this one, I'll use the innerHTML property,
  // which simply replaces all HTML under a tag.  This is the lazy way to do
  // it, and I personally don't use it.  But it's really popular and you are
  // welcome to use it.  Just know your shame if you do it...
  var messageDiv = document.getElementById("aSeats");
  messageDiv.innerHTML = response.aSeats;

  // replace our history by modifying the dom -- this is the right way
  // for simplicity, I'm just erasing the list and then repopulating it
  var aSeats = document.getElementById("aSeats");
  while (aSeats.childNodes.length > 0) { // clear it out
    aSeats.removeChild(aSeats.childNodes[0]);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < response.history.length; i++) { // add the items back in
    var option = aSeats.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response.history[i]));
  }

  // reset the input box
  //document.getElementById("pack").value = "";

}
</script>


<% Venue v = (Venue)session.getAttribute("currentVenue"); %>
<% List<Conceptual_Package> cpList = Conceptual_PackageDAO.getInstance().getByVenue(v.getId()); %>

What Packages do you want to see?

 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.Sale3PackAction.action">
 <select name="packid" id="pack">
     <% for (Conceptual_Package cp: cpList) { %>
    <option value="<%=cp.getId()%>"><%=cp.getName1()%></option>
    <% } %>


 </select>

    <input type="submit" value="  next  " onclick="getSeats();"/>

    </form>


<!--new-->


Available Seats:

 <select name="eventSeatid" id="aSeats">

    <option value="aSeats"></option>

 </select>


    <input type="button" value="  Add  "/>


Selected Seats:
 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.sale4Action.action">
     <select name="eventSeat2id" size="10" id="seat2">


     <option value="seat2"></option>




 </select>

    </form>



<jsp:include page="/footer.jsp"/>
```

-the json jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/plain" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:directive.page import="java.util.*"/>
{
  "history": [
<% for (String newSeats: (List<String>)session.getAttribute("newSeats")) { %>
      "<%=newSeats%>",
<% } %>
   ]
}
```

-the action class

```
public class Sale3PackAction implements Action{
    public String process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String packid = request.getParameter("packid");
        System.out.println("packid is: " + packid);
        Conceptual_Package cp = Conceptual_PackageDAO.getInstance().read(packid);
        request.setAttribute("cp", cp);
        List<Physical_Package> ppList = Physical_PackageDAO.getInstance().getByConceptual_Package(cp.getId());
        request.setAttribute("currentPack", ppList);
        session.setAttribute("aSeats", null);




        //return "sale3Pack_ajax.jsp";

        //new

        //HttpSession session = request.getSession();


        // ensure we have a history


       for (Physical_Package pPack: ppList){


        try {
            if (session.getAttribute("aSeats") == null) {
                LinkedList aSeatsList = new LinkedList<String>();
                session.setAttribute("aSeats", aSeatsList);

                    aSeatsList.add("Sec: " + pPack.getVenueSeat().getRowInVenue().getSectionInVenue().getSectionNumber() + " Row: " + pPack.getVenueSeat().getRowInVenue().getRowNumber() + " Seat: " + pPack.getVenueSeat().getSeatNumber());

                session.setAttribute("newSeats", aSeatsList);

            } else {
                LinkedList aSeatsList = (LinkedList) session.getAttribute("aSeats");

                    aSeatsList.add("Sec: " + pPack.getVenueSeat().getRowInVenue().getSectionInVenue().getSectionNumber() + " Row: " + pPack.getVenueSeat().getRowInVenue().getRowNumber() + " Seat: " + pPack.getVenueSeat().getSeatNumber());

                session.setAttribute("newSeats", aSeatsList);
            }

        } catch (DataException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sale3PackAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }


        // next jsp page to go to
        return "AjaxPack_json.jsp";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hehe, I think we've all been in your place. Spending hours on something just to eventually realize that we overlooked some simple detail.

*Read comments for more information...*

Comment: That may be it. I just added the rest of the code from that class so you can take a better look... Thanks for your help....I'm not going to lie I am DESPERATE...

Comment: haha thanks, if you could take a gander at the new code I posted above and let me know if you think that's my problem that would be great..

Comment: @John Leidegren - I made some changes so now that shouldn't be the problem but still getting the result.

Comment: @John Leidegren changed it.... still just displaying the data like the screenshot above. It's so annoying because I know it's one little thing

Comment: @Eric - Have you tried putting break points in your (JavaScript) code and stepping through the entire thing, inspecting variables as you step on? Can you reproduce the issue in a even more isolated manner?

Comment: Yes I have but I'll do it again and see what's going on, thanks for your help so far

Comment: @Eric - Well, feel free to throw any ideas you have or any discoveries you make at me. I'll look at it and add my two pennies worth.

Comment: found out this was the problem: ``</select>

    <input type="submit" value="  next  " onclick="getSeats();"/>

    </form> `` I changed it from ``submit`` to ``button`` and it came out great. The ``submit`` was forcing it to another page

Comment: Ah, I see now. I wasn't sure what you meant by "this is what is happening instead, (it's the right data):" but you where actually being navigated to the JSON response. There's also another way to do this and that's to change `onclick="getSeats();"` to `onclick="getSeats();return false;"` the issue here is that the default submit behavior is kicking in, it is disabled by simply returning false. Either way, nicely done tracking down the problem yourself.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when things go awry, I do not hesitate to dig into the HTTP traffic looking for any overly suspicious activity. It would have pointed me in the right direction right away. That necessitates learning some HTTP but if your a web developer, leaning HTTP is just good practice. It will give you a better understanding of what's going on in the future.

Comment: @John Leidegren You are awesome John!! Thanks so much for the help!!!! web dev is not what i am focusing on but i will definitely dive into http a little. thanks again